# Why some Object values get passed and some do not?

Tags: javascript

I have the following code in JavaScript, and for some reason it passes `this.id` to the `validator()` function but won't pass `this.min_chars`.
what could be the problem?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var inputs = {
        'first_name' : {id:"fn_input", type: "text", placeholder: "Jane",name: "First Name", min_chars: 2},
        'last_name' : {id:"ln_input", type: "text", placeholder: "Doe", name: "Last Name", min_chars: 5}
    };
    for(field in inputs){
        var ni = document.createElement("input"); // new input
        add_attributes(ni,inputs[field].id,'',inputs[field].type);
        ni.placeholder = (inputs[field].placeholder) ? inputs[field].placeholder : '';
        document.getElementById("in_" + inputs[field].id).appendChild(ni);

        var ned = document.createElement("span"); //new error div
        add_attributes(ned,"err_" + inputs[field].id,"reg_error");
        document.getElementById("in_" + inputs[field].id).appendChild(ned);
        ni.addEventListener("keyup",function(e){validator(e,this.id,this.min_chars);});
    }
});
function add_attributes(element,idn,classn,type){
    if(idn) element.setAttribute('id', idn);    
    if(classn) element.setAttribute('class',classn);
    if(type) element.type = type;
}
function validator(e,id,min_chars){
    var input = document.getElementById(id).value;

    if(input.length < 2){
        document.getElementById("err_" + id).innerHTML = "Must be over "+min_chars+" chars";
    }
    else{

    }
}
```

**EDIT:**
Ok so `this` seems to be the input element `ni` and since it does have an `id` attribute it gets passed. and since it doesnt have `min_chars` attribute it doesnt. the problem now is, because how JS works, if i assign variables instead of `this` only the last property value gets passed.

Comment: `this` isn't what you thing it is here. Also what's `ni`?

Comment: I think you have to pass `field.id` and `field.min_chars`

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek the input element, updated the code.

Comment: what do you mean with your edit ? Also wouldn't it be nice if there was a self descriptive language that would generate HTML ? Wait..

Comment: it seems like that the `addeventlistener` runs only after the for loop has finished running. so, all the `eventlistener` functions have the same parameters.

Comment: @Alex that's closures for you. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures but you don't have to learn that (yet, you should though) you can still use "this", like shown in my answer. Or use `let` instead of `vars`

Comment: Or use `let` instead of `var`

Comment: yup, thank you i just did that. works perfectly!

Comment: @Alex good to know, I hope you can accept my answer and upvote it if it helped then.

Answer (score 0):

So the element object doesn't have a min_char field. It doesn't even have a `min_chars` attribute. You can add an attribute to a tag with `setAttribute` and retrieve it with `getAttribute`

```
    var ni = document.createElement("input"); 
    ni.setAttribute("min_chars", 2);

[...]

   ni.addEventListener("keyup",function(e){
      console.log(this.getAttribute("min_chars"));
   });
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h3wfr01y/)